# Won't the absence of Infinity Stones affect the main timeline?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, infinity-stones

As the Ancient One explains to Bruce Banner:

> The Infinity Stones create what you experience as the flow of time. Remove one stone and that flow splits.

She asks Banner to return them to their respective locations correctly.

Won't the destruction of the 6 Stones impact the universe in the current timeline?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot affect the timeline because it was not previously created.
As it is the first occurence of this time destroying the stones, it could create a timeline but it become the main timeline as there is no others time where the stone was not destroyed.

To be completely clear, it will create a timeline only if the flow of time was previously made which is not the case in the present with Thanos.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're saying here but to be clear the Infinity Stones were never destroyed, only reduced to atoms.

Comment: Correct, One more reason to not create an alternative timeline about this event :)

Comment: I agree with LethalCarrot - your answer is very confusing. However, @LethalCarrot Thanos does say *"I used the stones to destroy the stones."* The line "reduced to atoms" is merely stating that they are effectively stating the extent of how far he went to destroy them. He didn't just break them - they were reduced to molecules, which is irreversible. You can't glue atoms back together.

Comment: @Ben “You can't glue atoms back together” — maybe *you* can't!

Comment: @Ben Exactly reduced to atoms and the "stone form" destroyed but they aren't destroyed destroyed.

Comment: Simply because you can't destroy matter.